# How to separate nylon 66 salt (hexamethylenediammonium adipate) into adipic acid and hexamethylenediamine?

Tags: hydrolysis

After hydrolyzing nylon 66 in water (neutral hydrolysis) in a batch autoclave reactor, the resulting solution contains the organic salt hexamethylenediammonium adipate.

Is there any way to precipitate either the acid or the amine from this solution?

Comment: Ion exchange chromatography would be straightforward. Or change the pH and then separate the [free base](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3510522A/en) or the [free acid](https://www.gea.com/en/binaries/adipic-acid-crystallization-gea_tcm11-34856.pdf) using crystallization. Or you could use solvent extraction.

Comment: Acidify your solution and cool it, adipic acid should crystallize out. It has a solubility of 17g/L in water so you will not get all of it first time.