# Is there any literature regarding the neutral hydrolysis of nylon 66?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, hydrolysis

I am working on a project for my thesis regarding the *neutral* hydrolysis of nylon 66 at high temperatures and pressures (265C,40 bar) however the only literature I could find relates to alkaline and acid hydrolysis. Is there any data that links to my project?

Comment: This looks relevent  https://hal.science/hal-01082759/document

Comment: Recently asked: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/171318/how-to-separate-nylon-66-salt-hexamethylenediammonium-adipate-into-adipic-acid

Comment: also check: https://projekter.aau.dk/projekter/files/414254361/TEPE4_1003_Thesis.pdf